# Can ngx-translate be used with database translations?

Tags: angular, pouchdb, ngx-translate

I have a large database (pouchDB) full of translations each languages translations is held in its own db. How would I use ngx-translate to get the translations directly from the db?

Comment: I think you'll need to pass all db entries to your application using an API call, then you should be able to read them. It would be good to see a few code, just to know what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

the first thing that you need to do is override the ini function in your app module because you need to download the translations before the app is fully displayed. In providers attribute of your app.module add this:

```
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (ini), deps: [
            HttpClient,
            TranslateService,
        ], multi: true
    }
```

also you need to create a custom translate loader and declared in your app.module when you declare de translate module

```
   TranslateModule.forRoot({
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createCustomTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http, RegionService]
    }),
```

the init function will return another function that return a observable. is here where you declare the translation service

```
       translate.addLangs(["en", "fr", "es"])
        translate.setDefaultLang("en")
        let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang()
        moment.locale(browserLang)
        translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr|es/) ? browserLang : "en")
```

the *createCustomTranslateLoader* method will return a class that extend from TranlasteLoader

```
export function createCustomTranslateLoader(http: Http, regionService: RegionService) {
    return new CustomTranslationLoader(http, regionService)
}
```

the class will re-implement a method that load the translations from the backend

```
export class CustomTranslationLoader extends TranslateLoader {

    constructor(private http: Http, private regionService: RegionService) {
       super()
    }

    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
     ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can for this you need:

1. implement REST method, that returns your translations for different languages;
   like `GET` `http://yourhost/rest/translation/en`;
2. And then you can install [package](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader) that provides ngx-translation for load your translations by Http, or implement your own service for this.

P. S: if you're still on Angular <4.3, please use Http from @angular/http with http-loader@0.1.0.